# Adding an integer to a float in PHP rounds the float to 1 decimal place

Tags: php, floating-point, rounding

For example, I have this line of code:

```
echo 10359023529 + 0.2137582935;
```

Why does this return:

> 10359023529.2

instead of:

> 10359023529.2137582935

Comment: There are one or more php.ini settings that state how many digits to print. I am not sure of which ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use: [`bcadd()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcadd.php)

```
echo bcadd(10359023529, 0.2137582935, 10);
```

Answer (score 3):

That's the limitation of a floating point value. A floating point value is stored as a coefficient and exponent. You'll have lots of precision with small numbers, and low precision with high numbers. Here is more detail than you would want: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008

Bottom line: High values will be very imprecise. Try to use a small value range.

Here's more about the floating point precision specifically in regards to PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

If you really need high precision and high numbers, look at BC math ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php ) and GMP ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php ).

Answer (score 1):

There is an obscure option in `php.ini` that defines how many significant digits to show when printing floating point numbers. In my case it looks as follows

```
; The number of significant digits displayed in floating point numbers.
; http://php.net/precision
precision = 14
```

Of course this deals only with formatting, not the fundamental fact that floating-point numbers are inherently imprecise. According to [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) the precision of double is 15.95 decimal digits.

Comment: The output precision isn't the issue; the float data type is only so precise.

Comment: In principle you are right, but in this particular case he didn't exceed the double precision.

Comment: @Adam I believe he did, actually; otherwise his implementation has been specifically set to only display one decimal place when outputting floating point numbers, as the default is 14.

Comment: Interestingly my command line PHP displays 10359023529.214 by default (precision 14).

Comment: @Adam Then at a guess I'd say your platform has higher precision floating point numbers than James'

Comment: I don't think so, the precision of double is exactly defined by the IEEE 754 standard as 15.95 decimal digits.